# should words in this sentence be flipped around a bit?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, british-english, learning

In this Headline:

"New Inflation Developments Are Rattling Markets and Economists. Here’s Why.

Inflation is less about pandemic and war surprises and more about economic momentum. That could make the solution more painful."

should OR could I rewrite the "pandemic and war surprises" part  as "surprises pandemic and war"?

the later way seems more neat.

Comment: What do you mean when you reorder the words?  Are you thinking of three things: surprises, and pandemics, and wars? Or are you thinking of two things: the surprise of a pandemic and the surprise of a war?

Comment: *She likes rich and powerful men* could in principle be resequenced to *She likes men rich and powerful*, but that's a very unlikely / "poetic, literary" form that you'll rarely need to know about. You *might* see something similar with a "relativiser" element *(She likes men **who are** rich and powerful).* Or perhaps with an "emphatic" element if two "incongruous" qualities are specified, as in *He likes women **both** fat and thin* (meaning *He likes **all** women, regardless of whether they're fat or thin*). But again, this is a highly stylised "literary" usage.

Answer (score 1):

I would not change the order.  It is not *impossible* to re-order the words, but it would change the feeling of the writing and make it maybe less clear.

In the phrase "pandemic and war surprises", the real noun is *surprises*.  The nouns *pandemic* and *war* are being used as modifiers: these are *pandemic surprises* and *war surprises*.  We normally use nouns as adjuncts in front of the nouns that they modify, like "*horse* race" vs "*motorcycle* race".

You could write "...less about surprises, pandemic or war, and more..." but using that kind of word order is very poetic - it's like saying "races, horse or motorcycle" - and is not the kind of style that newspapers prefer to use.

Comment: nice explanation also you've mentioned the example: "...less about surprises, pandemic or war, and more...". Could I use it like: "...less about surprises pandemic or war, and more..." without the comma after surprises ?

Comment: The usage of commas is sometimes more of a stylistic choice than one about strict rules, but no, I wouldn't use it without the commas.  In fact, I might prefer to fill out the sentence even more: "...less about surprises, be they pandemic or war, and more..."  When you're using a non-standard word order, it's best to make the sentence as clear as possible to reduce confusion, and writing "surprises pandemic" is like writing "races horse": it just isn't standard.

Comment: I get your point. Although I think "horse races" and "races horse" has different meaning, so in this case I lose the gist if flip words